# jQuery not working in Wordpress 3.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

So I seem to have an issue with one of my old Wordpress themes. I just brought one of my themes out of the darkness to use as a piece of my portfolio, and immediately realized that my jQuery sidebar has completely stopped working and I'm not sure why. Now mind you, I wrote this bit of sidebar code before WordPress implemented their own 'custom' sidebar implementations (so I'm very unsure if this relates to that but highly doubt it. I think I developed it around the time of Wordpress 3.1). The specific code at fault is located here

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/sliding_effect.js"></script> <!-- code for jquery menu -->

<?php wp_head(); ?>  

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".button-slide").click(function()
    {
        $("#slide-panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});

</script>

</head>
```

I know the jQuery version is out of date, but even after updating it I was still unsuccessful. Does anyone have a clue on what I am doing wrong. I'll happily provide more code if needed. All of the above is located in my header.php file within my theme.

Here's a portion of the implementation

```
<ul id="sliding-navigation">

<br/>




<!-- Panel -->

<li class= "sliding-element"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/TheEntertainmentArt/208687212498902" target="_TOP" " title="TheEntertainmentArt">Join Us On Facebook!</a></li>

     <li class="sliding-element"><h3>Menu</h3></li>

     <li class="sliding-element"><a href= "http://theentertainmentart.info/category/ps3">Playstation 3</a></li>
     <li class="sliding-element"><a href= "http://theentertainmentart.info/category/360">Xbox 360</a></li>
     <li class="sliding-element"><a href= "http://theentertainmentart.info/category/wii">Wii</a></li>
     <li class="sliding-element"><a href= "http://theentertainmentart.info/category/film">Film</a></li>
     <li class="sliding-element"><a href= "http://theentertainmentart.info/category/music">Music</a></li>
     <li class="sliding-element"><a href= "http://theentertainmentart.info/category/art">Art</a></li>
     <li class="sliding-element"><a href= "http://theentertainmentart.info/category/coding">Coding</a></li>
      <li class="sliding-element"><a href= "http://theentertainmentart.info/category/uncategorized">Misc</a></li>
```

and some CSS

```
  #navigation-block {
        position:relative;
        /*top:100px;
        left:100px;*/
    }

    #hide {
        position:absolute;
        top:30px;
        left:-190px;
    }

    ul#sliding-navigation
    {

        list-style: none;
        /*font-size: .75em;*/
        font-size: 1em;
        /*margin: 30px 0;*/
        padding: 0;
        width: 175px;



    }
ul#sliding-navigation li.sliding-element h3,
ul#sliding-navigation li.sliding-element a
{
    display: block;
    width: 175px;

    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    /* corner code */
    /*border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    border-top-right-radius: 50px;
    border-top-left-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 50px;*/
    -moz-border-radius: 1em 4em 1em 4em;
    border-radius: 1em 4em 1em 4em;
    border: outset;


}
```

sliding_effect.js

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    slide("#sliding-navigation", 25, 15, 150, .8);
});

function slide(navigation_id, pad_out, pad_in, time, multiplier)
{
    // creates the target paths
    var list_elements = navigation_id + " li.sliding-element";
    var link_elements = list_elements + " a";

    // initiates the timer used for the sliding animation
    var timer = 0;

    // creates the slide animation for all list elements 
    $(list_elements).each(function(i)
    {
        // margin left = - ([width of element] + [total vertical padding of element])
        $(this).css("margin-left","-180px");
        // updates timer
        timer = (timer*multiplier + time);
        $(this).animate({ marginLeft: "0" }, timer);
        $(this).animate({ marginLeft: "15px" }, timer);
        $(this).animate({ marginLeft: "0" }, timer);
    });

    // creates the hover-slide effect for all link elements         
    $(link_elements).each(function(i)
    {
        $(this).hover(
        function()
        {
            $(this).animate({ paddingLeft: pad_out }, 150);
        },      
        function()
        {
            $(this).animate({ paddingLeft: pad_in }, 150);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: I'm currently using Dreamweaver (CS5). To my knowledge, I don't believe there is a console output. Is there anything in particular I should be looking for?

Comment: So if you are using something like Firebug, Chrome developer tools, etc. (if not you should be) you have a javascript console available to you which will show you any javascript errors. Was just wondering if you are getting javascript errors.

Comment: Press F12 in your browser of choice.  Click the console tab.  Report back with any errors you see :)

Comment: Right before you said that I went for a website console. This is the error I'm getting: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $    The error references the line that starts this $(document).ready(function(){
$(".button-slide").click(function(){
$("#slide-panel").slideToggle("slow");
});
});
</script> or in other words the start of my jQuery

Comment: I added a jQuery.js file (containing the version of jQuery this was built on 1.3 I think) and ran the site. These are the errors I'm getting: http://localhost/TheEntertainmentArt/TEA/js/jquery.jsFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost/TheEntertainmentArt/TEA/js/sliding_effect.jsFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)   The files are there, not sure what is going on. Above I've included my sliding_effect code.

Comment: The last version of jQuery to load will be the one used.  Stop loading your own jQuery and learn how to use wp_enqueue_script().

Comment: @Chris_O. I honestly already tried this with the same bit of failure. I did read the documentation. I've also read about the benefits of using google's loaded jQuery versus the wp_enqueue_script().

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure including 2 different versions of jQuery on the same page won't cause any problems?

The jQuery version WordPress ships with (which might get included when you call wp_head(); ) loads in the no conflict mode. This is explained [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers):

Basically you need to wrap your script with

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // $() will work as an alias for jQuery() inside of this function
});
```

Comment: If you look above, my actual sliding_effect code is wrapped in that. Is the $ instead of jQuery possibly causing conflict? Maybe I'm just not completely understanding what your saying. Could you show me what you mean with the reference code above?

Comment: notice also the dollar sign in function($). Please see the link I posted, it contains many other kinds of wrapper functions that might suit your needs.

edit: slow reading

Comment: @TheGamingArt - based on your previous comment where you get an error: "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $", then yes, it's the $. Change the $ to jQuery and see if that works.

Comment: I'll have to give this a shot and revise everything. The first shot I had didn't make a difference. At some point in history, it seems I dumped the jQuery because of the problems it was giving me anyways. No idea why this is soo ... well... not as simple as it should be.

Comment: My #1 advice would be not to include multiple instances of jQuery, that will cause problems and excess calls are an overhead to the client. Inpect your generated source and see if you can find more than one <script src="...somewhere/something_jquery.js"></script>