# Jquery conflict between two diffrent libraries

Tags: jquery, anythingslider

I recently added parallax scroling on a wordpress page where there are several other plugins.

The problem is that the jQuery parallax plugin conflicts with the `anythingSlider` plugin and it gives me the error `Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function`.

I know that you can use `$.noConflict();` but I've probably not used it correctly. The code where the error appears is:

```
$(function() {
    jQuery('#slider-{$id}').anythingSlider({  
    enter code here`...
```

Comment: Please show us where you have scripts included in your page and where you added `noConflict()`

Comment: Wordpress runs in noconflict mode anyway, replace `$(function() {` with `jQuery(function() {` - see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14288939/2287470

Comment: The jquery I added is in the footer. But I suspect that the plugin inserts the jQuery in my header.

Any suggestions?